# QObject::connect local pointer variable

Tags: c++, qt

I need to use obj object inside SLOT function. I can pass obj with [`this`] in lambda.

1.But need to know if SLOT will keep a pointer variable to obj after
`newObjptr` went out of scope?

2.Will work until `newObjptr` location re-used at runtime?

```
Object* obj = new Object(); // global object

void function()
{
   Object* newObjptr = obj;
   QObject::connect(sender, signal, [newObjptr](){

      //need to use newObjptr here. Will this fails??
});
}
```

Comment: If you're asking whether `obj` will be deleted when `function()` returns, the answer is no -- objects allocated with `new` will only be deleted when your code (or somebody's code) explicitly calls `delete` on them.

Comment: Remember that pointers are still just only values (think of them as "integers" denoting a place in memory). So if you pass a pointer value, this means that the "integer" value is copied to lambda. But this value is completely unrelated of the fact what data is in the memory to which this pointer points to (is there any object? is it live? was it deleted?). So to answer your question: the validity of your code will only depend on the lifetime of the object which occupies the memory. It does not depend on whether the "integer" value (i.e. the pointer) gets out of scope.